# Does this question about transitioning fit the scope?

Tags: discussion, scope

This question about [whether impact of transitioning from meat eater to pescatarian is comparable to transitioning from pescatarian to vegan](https://vegetarianism.stackexchange.com/q/2175/164) appeared in the Close queue. I am not sure how well it fits the scope of the site, mainly because of the *pescatarian* being the "middle step" since that doesn't fall under vegetarianism/veganism.